# Custom fonts wont work in android

Tags: android, fonts, titanium

Using Titanium studios; So i got this font in both my resource/fonts folder, android/fonts folder, root/assets/fonts; and I Cant find what I got wrong with my code.
The only conclusion is that the font wont work with android at all.
My teacher could'nt find the solution either.

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet.

http://pastie.org/8722990

Comment: I might be wrong, but why are you not using eclipse?

Comment: Because we use Titnium in school and are not allowed to use other software to develop apps in this course, also isnt the use of software kind of subjective? no?

Comment: Well, it actually depends, if you want to create a program, utility and not a game eclipse is probably the best otherwise there many more. This might help you. [Here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Custom+Fonts)

Comment: have you try with this [guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts) at this point: **Rename font file to match PostScript name** ?

Comment: Up-voted for: `I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet.`

Comment: Yes I have checked out the Guide on appcelerator. It didnt work for some resason, thats why i turned to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fontSize` and `fontFamily` properties need to go in a `font {}` object, e.g.

```
var titel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Hur låter..?",
    color : "white",
    textAlign : "center",
    bottom : "85%",
    font: { 
        fontSize : 45,
        fontFamily : 'customFont'
    }
});
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Font